# After Effects - No preview window after reopening my project

Tags: after-effects

I just reopened my project and in all compositions that have 3D layers the preview is gone:

[image]

It looks like a bug to me but maybe I'm missing something?

ps: don't mind the lack of timeline, it's on a second display.

Comment: That looks like the preview panel is just not opened in your current workspace. Have you tried resetting it under window -> workspace -> reset active workspace (or something along these lines)?

Comment: Yes I tried. The preview panel is fine because it work ok on Compositions without any 3D layers. If I create a new Composition and include a 3D layer it looks fine, but after restarting AE it disappears, only rulers remain in place.

Comment: If *Window>Workspace>Reset Standard Workspace* as Gin-San mentioned don't solves the issue, you should send for all of us a bug report to adobe.

Comment: Check that the current time of the composition is not before the beginning or after the end of the composition. This can happen if you have linked compositions and they don't all start / finish at the same time.

Comment: @stib good point!